# Jquery to replace a specific image with an iframe

Tags: jquery, image, iframe

I am trying to customize a bio page for an employee where I work, and my jQuery I've written isn't working and I'm lost on how to get it to work. The employee bios get their info from a database, and within these pages are thumbnail images of the employee's work samples, which get their specifics (such as "RobertThumb1.jpg") from the database. I don't want to rewrite the html or php on the page just to accommodate one employee, and then have to go back in and fix 1000+ employees' database entries for that field, so I want to use jQuery to replace his thumbnail image with an iframe from the site he puts his music on. I've made a jsfiddle of this problem using fake info (other than the real iframe), and you can see what I've done there. https://jsfiddle.net/0vfyduk2/12/

Here's the html from my fiddle:

```
<!--this works-->
<span id="phone"><strong>Phone:&nbsp; </strong>999-999-Robert</span>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!--this works-->
<a id="firstthumb" target="_blank" href="http://www.corporatetraveller.ca/assets/images/profile-placeholder.gif">Gary</a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!--this is the one that my jquery isn't working on-->
<a id="secondthumb" target="_blank" href="http://www.corporatetraveller.ca/assets/images/profile-placeholder.gif"><img class="publicationthumbnails contrast2" style="width:19%; height:auto; float:left; margin-right:1%; padding:0;" src="http://www.corporatetraveller.ca/assets/images/profile-placeholder.gif"></a>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<!--for the 4th one, which doesn't work either-->
<a id="thirdthumb" target="_blank" href="http://www.corporatetraveller.ca/assets/images/profile-placeholder.gif"><img class="publicationthumbnails contrast2" style="width:19%; height:auto; float:left; margin-right:1%; padding:0;" src="http://www.corporatetraveller.ca/assets/images/profile-placeholder.gif"></a>
```

and the jQuery is below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/*this works (if you remove my code below that does not work)*/
$('span#phone:contains("999-999-Robert")').html("<strong>Phone:&nbsp; </strong>222-333-9999");

/*this works (if you remove my code below that does not work)*/
$('a#firstthumb:contains("Gary")').html("bob");

/*this is what I need help with to make it work*/
$("a#secondthumb:contains('img[src*="profile-placeholder.gif"]')").html("<iframe width="100%" height="265" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://www.reverbnation.com/widget_code/html_widget/artist_2472492?widget_id=55&pwc[included_songs]=1&context_type=page_object&pwc[size]=small&pwc[color]=light" style="width:0px;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;"></iframe>");

/*this is a simplified version without the iframe code of what isn't working above, and it doesn't work either*/
$("a#thirdthumb:contains('img[src*="profile-placeholder.gif"]')").html("Larry");

});
```

Can a jQuery expert figure out what I'm doing wrong? I can't even get the selector to even select what I'm trying to select.

Comment: If it's helpful, this is what I referenced to try to write the code: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: Your use of the :contains selector is a bit odd.  Normally that selector just checks against the text inside the element, not attributes of the element itself.

Comment: You also have a few places where the single quote and double quote are overly nested causing the string to be incorrect.  Notice that in the fiddle the coloring changes as it senses this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector is predominately used for text content and not actual selectors. If you wanted to use in that manner, simply target the element as expected and then set it's contents :

```
// Find find all of the img tags that meet your criteria and replace the parents
$("a#secondthumb img[src*='profile-placeholder.gif']").each(function(){
    // Find the closest <a> tag and set the contents
    $(this).closest('a').html("<iframe width='100%' height='265' scrolling='no' frameborder='no' src='https://www.reverbnation.com/widget_code/html_widget/artist_2472492?widget_id=55&pwc[included_songs]=1&context_type=page_object&pwc[size]=small&pwc[color]=light' style='width:0px;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;'></iframe>");
});
```

Likewise, if you just wanted to replace the images themselves, you could just use :

```
$("a#secondthumb img[src*='profile-placeholder.gif']").html(...);
```

Additionally, you appeared to have some quote-related mixups (i.e. unescaped quotes or mismatched single and double quotes that could have caused jQuery to have trouble reading your content.

**Example**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--this works-->
  <span id="phone"><strong>Phone:&nbsp; </strong>999-999-Robert</span>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <!--this works-->
  <a id="firstthumb" target="_blank" href="http://www.corporatetraveller.ca/assets/images/profile-placeholder.gif">Gary</a>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <!--this is the one that my jquery isn't working on-->
  <a id="secondthumb" target="_blank" href="http://www.corporatetraveller.ca/assets/images/profile-placeholder.gif">
    <img class="publicationthumbnails contrast2" style="width:19%; height:auto; float:left; margin-right:1%; padding:0;" src="http://www.corporatetraveller.ca/assets/images/profile-placeholder.gif">
  </a>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <!--for the 4th one, which doesn't work either-->
  <a id="thirdthumb" target="_blank" href="http://www.corporatetraveller.ca/assets/images/profile-placeholder.gif">
    <img class="publicationthumbnails contrast2" style="width:19%; height:auto; float:left; margin-right:1%; padding:0;" src="http://www.corporatetraveller.ca/assets/images/profile-placeholder.gif">
  </a>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      /*this works (if you remove my code below that does not work)*/
      $('span#phone:contains("999-999-Robert")').html("<strong>Phone:&nbsp; </strong>222-333-9999");

      /*this works (if you remove my code below that does not work)*/
      $('a#firstthumb:contains("Gary")').html("bob");

      /*this is what I need help with to make it work*/
      $("a#secondthumb img[src*='profile-placeholder.gif']").each(function() {
        $(this).closest('a').html("<iframe width='100%' height='265' scrolling='no' frameborder='no' src='https://www.reverbnation.com/widget_code/html_widget/artist_2472492?widget_id=55&pwc[included_songs]=1&context_type=page_object&pwc[size]=small&pwc[color]=light' style='width:0px;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;'></iframe>");
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh wow! That does work! Thank you so much! I found another solution that works as well, after looking through more documentation, but I think yours might be a better solution! Thank you!!!

Comment: $('a#secondthumb[href="http://www.corporatetraveller.ca/assets/images/profile-placeholder.gif"]').html('<iframe width="100%" height="265" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://www.reverbnation.com/widget_code/html_widget/artist_2472492?widget_id=55&pwc[included_songs]=1&context_type=page_object&pwc[size]=small&pwc[color]=light" style="width:0px;min-width:100%;max-width:100%;"></iframe>');

Is what I tried and it worked